# Why ant.design <Upload> component cancel upload request when setState?

Tags: reactjs, antd

1. I have a form with upload component using ant.design
2. But every time I upload an image, the request aborted.
3. I figure out the `setState()` method call in the `onChange` handler caused the abort.
4. The code was copied from the ant.design website example: https://ant.design/components/upload-cn/#components-upload-demo-avatar
5. I don't know what's wrong here, I wasted too much time on this...
6. this is my code, you can try on https://codesandbox.io/s/wopv2xn1k5

```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Upload, Form, Icon } from 'antd';

function getBase64(img, callback) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}

class AddBookForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
    };

    handleChange = (info) => {
        if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            return;
        }
        if (info.file.status === 'done') {
            // Get this url from response in real world.
            getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl => this.setState({
                imageUrl,
                loading: false,
            }));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const formItemLayout = { labelCol: { xs: 24, sm: 2 }, wrapperCol: { xs: 24, sm: 8 } };
        const FormItem = function(props) {
            return <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} {...props}></Form.Item>;
        };
        const uploadButton = (
            <div>
                <Icon type={this.state.loading ? 'loading' : 'plus'} />
                <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
            </div>
        );
        const imageUrl = this.state.imageUrl;

        return (
            <Form layout="horizontal">
                <FormItem label="图片" extra="请上传2M以内的JPG图片">
                        <Upload
                            name='imageFile'
                            action="/api/image-upload"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            showUploadList={false}
                            listType="picture-card"
                            className="single-image-uploader"
                        >
                            {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="" /> : uploadButton}
                        </Upload>
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <AddBookForm />
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### UPDATE 2018-05-25:

This problem solve after I change the `<FormItem>` Component from Stateless Functional Component to a class component.

```
class FormItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const formItemLayout = { labelCol: { xs: 24, sm: 2 }, wrapperCol: { xs: 24, sm: 8 } };
        return <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} {...this.props}></Form.Item>
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be a problem with your server running at `/api/image-upload`.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk I hope that, so I won't spent so much time on this, but the serve is running OK, have you try my online demo I gave above? The request still abort even there is not a server.